# TinyMCE Changing empty html attributes

Tags: html, attributes, tinymce

So, i have config TinyMCE:

```
    valid_elements : '*[*]', extended_valid_elements: '*[*]',
```

But it changing my code from:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"></div>
```

To:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"></div>
```

How to disable this changing?